# algorithm - warping image to another image and calculate similarity measure

Tags: algorithm, opencv

I have a query on calculation of best matching point of one image to another image through intensity based registration. I'd like to have some comments on my algorithm:

1. Compute the warp matrix at this iteration
2. For every point of the image A,

   2a. We warp the particular image A pixel coordinates with the warp matrix to image B

   2b. Perform interpolation to get the corresponding intensity form image B if warped point coordinate is in image B.

   2c. Calculate the similarity measure value between warped pixel A intensity and warped image B intensity
3. Cycle through every pixel in image A
4. Cycle through every possible rotation and translation

Would this be okay? Is there any relevant opencv code we can reference?

Answer (score 0):

## Comments on algorithm

Your algorithm appears good although you will have to be careful about:

1. Edge effects: You need to make sure that the algorithm does not favour matches where most of image A does not overlap image B.  e.g. you may wish to compute the average similarity measure and constrain the transformation to make sure that at least 50% of pixels overlap.
2. Computational complexity.  There may be a lot of possible translations and rotations to consider and this algorithm may be too slow in practice.
3. Type of warp.  Depending on your application you may also need to consider perspective/lighting changes as well as translation and rotation.

## Acceleration

A similar algorithm is commonly used in video encoders, although most will ignore rotations/perspective changes and just search for translations.

One approach that is quite commonly used is to do a gradient search for the best match.  In other words, try tweaking the translation/rotation in a few different ways (e.g. left/right/up/down by 16 pixels) and pick the best match as your new starting point.  Then repeat this process several times.
Once you are unable to improve the match, reduce the size of your tweaks and try again.

## Alternative algorithms

Depending on your application you may want to consider some alternative methods:

1. Stereo matching.  If your 2 images come from stereo camera then you only really need to search in one direction (and OpenCV provides useful [methods](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findstereocorrespondencegc) to do this)
2. Known patterns.  If you are able to place a known pattern (e.g. a chessboard) in both your images then it becomes a lot easier to register them (and OpenCV provides [methods](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners) to find and register certain types of pattern)
3. Feature point matching.  A common approach to image registration is to search for distinctive points (e.g. types of corner or more general places of interest) and then try to find matching distinctive points in the two images.  For example, OpenCV contains functions to detect [SURF](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html#extractsurf) features.  Google has published a great [paper](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub37744.html) on using this kind of approach in order to remove rolling shutter noise that I recommend reading.